# Java while loop doesn't want stop

Tags: java, while-loop, java-7

I'm learning Java programming and have a problem with this code. My issue is I can't stop the second while loop (`while (done ==1){ .. }`)

If I do done = 2, the program resume...

```
int stopme3 = 1;
while (stopme3 == 1) {        
    /* Appel de la méthode Afficher les propriétaires */
    AfficherProprio();
    int choix_proprio = ChoisirProprio();

    /* Appel de la méthode Afficher les Comptes du Propriétaire */
    AfficherComptesProprietaire(choix_proprio);

    /* Choix du compte à modifier */
    System.out.println("N° de compte:");
    int choixCompte = lectureClavier.nextInt();
    /* Test si comptes existants du proprio */
    if (choixCompte == tab_compte[choix_proprio]._num_compte) {
        int done = 1;
        while (done == 1) {
            /* Création d'une ligne comptable */
            tab_compte[choix_proprio].CreerLigneC();
            System.out.println("Ajouter une ligne comptable supplémentaire ?");
            System.out.println("1 - Oui");
            System.out.println("2 - Non");
            done = lectureClavier.nextInt();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Compte sélectionné inexistant.");
    }
}
```

Help is much appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: Ah, nice French code, very readable for everyone on the internet. He does change `done`, at `done = lectureClavier.nextInt();` `lectureClavier` appears to mean keyboard.

Comment: What is the data which comes from `lectureClavier.nextInt()`?

Comment: The issue is not in `done` its in `stopme3` which stays int, the outer loop keeps going.

Comment: Dystroy: I do not understand your question, sorry.
Epsilon: lectureClavier.nextInt() ask to user if he want to continue or stop the boucle. (1 to continue, any other to stop)

Comment: Philipp: Yes, lectureClavier means keyboard ;)

Comment: @Philipp English isn't everyone's first language, and there is absolutely no reason why the French variable/method names should matter. The person could have named them `sillyCat1`, `sillyCat2`, and `sillyCat3()`and it still wouldn't have mattered for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int stopme3 = 1;
            while (stopme3 == 1) { // This loop will keep running till condition is true


int done = 1;
    while (done == 1) {// This loop will keep running till condition is true
```

Hence this will run infinitely. Hence you might want to do this way

```
  int stopme3 = 1;
  while (stopme3 == 1) { 

   if(some condition is met){
           stopme3  =2;
       }

}
```

Comment: He was talking about the inner loop `(while (done ==1){ .. })` not being finite. Your suggestion is about the outer loop.

Comment: Thanks you very much, it works now. :)

I have added : 

                                if (done != 1) {
                                    done = 2;
                                    stopme3 = 2;
                                }